# Wordpress - How to change class name in wp_list_page nav

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Wordpress's wp_list_pages to display a nav of pages on the site.

Some pages have children so I need a dropdown menu below those links.

The html is something like this

```
<ul class="">
    <li class="page_item page-item-6 current_page_item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-6 current_page_item"><a href="/">Profile</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-8 page_item_has_children dropdown">
        <a href="">Products &#038; Services</a>
        <ul class='children'>
            <li class="page_item page-item-17"><a href="">Buying</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-19"><a href="">Selling</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-23"><a href="">Managing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I wanted to use bootstrap to create the nav and dropdown menus.

Something like - http://www.ttmt.org.uk/nav/

The html for this is something like this.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to add a 'dropdown' class the li and ul containing the child pages. I also need to add a class and a data-toggle attribute to the 'a' tag.

How can I add these clases when I using wp_list_pages and the nav is created dynamically.

I'm using this function to add 'dropdown' to li containin the child pages

```
function add_parent_class( $css_class, $page, $depth, $args ){
    if ( ! empty( $args['has_children'] ) )
        $css_class[] = 'dropdown';
    return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'add_parent_class', 10, 4 );
```

How could I extened this function add the other classes I need

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this functionality, we can not use filters only. We will have to extend the Walker class of WordPress.

I am assuming that you have called wp_list_pages like this:

```
$args = array('authors' => '',
    'child_of' => 0,
    'date_format' => get_option( 'date_format' ),
    'depth' => 0,
    'echo' => 1,
    'exclude' => '',
    'include' => '',
    'link_after' => '',
    'link_before' => '',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'show_date' => '',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
    'sort_order' => '',
    'title_li' => __( '' ),
    'walker' => '',
);

echo '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">' . wp_list_pages( $args ) . '</ul>' ;
```

We will pass value to walker paramter. That paramter would be object of a class that we will create now. Add this class in functions.php of your theme or in [site specific plugin](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/what-why-and-how-tos-of-creating-a-site-specific-wordpress-plugin/)

```
class Wdm_Walker_Page extends Walker_Page {

/**
 * @see Walker::start_lvl()
 * @since 2.1.0
 *
 * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @param int $depth Depth of page. Used for padding.
 * @param array $args
 */
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='dropdown-menu children'>\n";
}

/**
 * @see Walker::start_el()
 * @since 2.1.0
 *
 * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @param object $page Page data object.
 * @param int $depth Depth of page. Used for padding.
 * @param int $current_page Page ID.
 * @param array $args
 */
function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_page = 0 ) {
    if ( $depth )
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    else
        $indent = '';

    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
    $css_class = array('page_item', 'page-item-'.$page->ID);

    if( isset( $args['pages_with_children'][ $page->ID ] ) )
        $css_class[] = 'page_item_has_children dropdown';

    if ( !empty($current_page) ) {
        $_current_page = get_post( $current_page );
        if ( in_array( $page->ID, $_current_page->ancestors ) )
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
        if ( $page->ID == $current_page )
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
        elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent )
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
    } elseif ( $page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
        $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
    }

    /**
     * Filter the list of CSS classes to include with each page item in the list.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     *
     * @see wp_list_pages()
     *
     * @param array   $css_class    An array of CSS classes to be applied
     *                             to each list item.
     * @param WP_Post $page         Page data object.
     * @param int     $depth        Depth of page, used for padding.
     * @param array   $args         An array of arguments.
     * @param int     $current_page ID of the current page.
     */
    $css_class = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'page_css_class', $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) );

    if ( '' === $page->post_title )
        $page->post_title = sprintf( __( '#%d (no title)' ), $page->ID );

    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
            if(preg_match('/dropdown/', $css_class) != FALSE){
    $output .= $indent . '<li class="' . $css_class . '"><a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . $link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) . $link_after . '</a>';
            }
            else{
                $output .= $indent . '<li class="' . $css_class . '"><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . $link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) . $link_after . '</a>';
            }

    if ( !empty($show_date) ) {
        if ( 'modified' == $show_date )
            $time = $page->post_modified;
        else
            $time = $page->post_date;

        $output .= " " . mysql2date($date_format, $time);
    }
    }
}
```

Above class adds all the classes you wanted.

Now, we need to pass the object of this class to wp_list_pages. So it would look something like this

```
$args = array(
                    'authors' => '',
                    'child_of' => 0,
                    'date_format' => get_option( 'date_format' ),
                    'depth' => 0,
                    'echo' => 1,
                    'exclude' => '',
                    'include' => '',
                    'link_after' => '',
                    'link_before' => '',
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'show_date' => '',
                    'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
                    'sort_order' => '',
                    'title_li' => __( '' ),
                    'walker' => new Wdm_Walker_Page()
                );

echo '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">' . wp_list_pages( $args ) . '</ul>' ;
```

I Hope it helps! You don't need to write code on filter `page_css_class` anymore. :)